# Filter out empty element documents

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb4.0

We have a shop collection as below.
We need to return all UNIQUE `'shop'` having NO batch as empty(`[]`).

Since this is a stage in the aggregation - it would not be able to avail of index.
So we need to find the most efficient way to do the above.

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("xxxxxx"),
    "shop": "Q4",
    "batch": ["5647"],
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("xxxxxx"),
    "shop": "Q4",
    "batch": ["2314", "0121"],
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("xxxxxx"),
    "shop": "Q1",
    "batch": ["5647"],
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("xxxxxx"),
    "shop": "Q1",
    "batch": [],
}
```

Expected result : Q4

Comment: can you describe your output, or you just want name of shop, `Q4`

Comment: Just names of unique shops as list/array

Comment: it would be better understable if you can put sample output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
db.shop.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: '', shop: { $addToSet: '$shop' },
        emptyBatchShops: { $push: { $cond: [{ $eq: ['$batch', []] }, '$shop', null] } }
    }
}, { $project: { _id :0, uniques: { $setDifference: ["$shop", "$emptyBatchShops"] } } }])
```

**Collection Data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e33c4daa855df1587760621"),
    "shop" : "Q4",
    "batch" : [ 
        "5647"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e33c4daa855df1587760622"),
    "shop" : "Q4",
    "batch" : [ 
        "2314", 
        "0121"
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e33c4daa855df1587760623"),
    "shop" : "Q1",
    "batch" : [ 
        "5647"
    ]
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e33c4daa855df1587760624"),
    "shop" : "Q1",
    "batch" : []
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e33c8fca855df1587760625"),
    "shop" : "Q5",
    "batch" : [ 
        "5647"
    ]
}

/* 6 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e33c8fca855df1587760626"),
    "shop" : "Q5",
    "batch" : [ 
        "5647"
    ]
}

/* 7 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e33c907a855df1587760627"),
    "shop" : "Q6",
    "batch" : []
}

/* 8 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e33c907a855df1587760628"),
    "shop" : "Q6",
    "batch" : [ 
        "5647"
    ]
}

/* 9 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e33c90ea855df1587760629"),
    "shop" : "Q7",
    "batch" : []
}

/* 10 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e33c90ea855df158776062a"),
    "shop" : "Q8",
    "batch" : [ 
        "5647"
    ]
}
```

**Result :**

```
{
    "uniques" : [ 
        "Q5", 
        "Q4", 
        "Q8"
    ]
}
```

Comment: push with cond will create duplicate entries

Comment: @IUnknown : No, it doesn't matter about pushing entries to `emptyBatchShops` cause you'll have uniques in `shops` which is what matters to us. So this query would work as expected.. Test it here :: https://mongoplayground.net/p/4RyGUnXJCbb

Answer (score 0):

Here is the aggregate query,

**Input**:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e33c96b08591b1809677543"),
    "shop" : "Q5",
    "batch" : [
        "5857",
        "5837"
    ]
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e33c95a08591b1809677542"),
    "shop" : "Q5",
    "batch" : [
        "5657"
    ]
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e33c93008591b1809677540"),
    "shop" : "Q1",
    "batch" : [
        "5648",
        "5628"
    ]
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e33c2fe08591b180967753f"),
    "shop" : "Q1",
    "batch" : [ ]
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e33c2fe08591b180967753e"),
    "shop" : "Q1",
    "batch" : [
        "5647"
    ]
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e33c2fe08591b180967753d"),
    "shop" : "Q4",
    "batch" : [
        "2314",
        "0121"
    ]
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e33c2fe08591b180967753c"),
    "shop" : "Q4",
    "batch" : [
        "5647"
    ]
}
```

**Query:**

```
const query = [
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$shop",
            batch: { $push: "$batch" }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            'batch': { $ne: [] }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1
        }
    }

];

db.trades.aggregate(query)
```

**Result**:

```
{
    "_id" : "Q5"
},     
{
    "_id" : "Q4"
}
```

Comment: Just the unique shop name/s - { "_id" : "REQC4" }{ "_id" : "...." }

Comment: it is not giving me unique entries - instead i get duplicate shops

Comment: based on your input it gives correct please check or provide more data to check

Comment: Thre should be only Q4 - as its the only one with NO empty array

Comment: I have changed the input as well plese check

Answer (score 0):

I tried this aggregation:

```
db.shops.aggregate( [
  { 
      $group: { 
          _id: "$shop", 
          hasEmptyBatches: { $addToSet: { $cond: [ {$eq: [ { $size: "$batch" }, 0 ] }, true, false ] } } 
      } 
  },
  { 
      $match: { hasEmptyBatches: { $ne: true } } 
  }
] )
```